Referencing lookup tables internal to a Python package
I'm putting some code into a package called lunch.
In one module I load a lookup table that is used throughout.
# module menu
import pandas as pd

# load menu
lk_egg = pd.DataFrame({
        'Item': [1, 2, 3],
        'Type': ['Poached', 'Fried', 'Boiled']})

In a second module I return the type:
# module eggs
from lunch import menu

def pickegg(item):
         return menu.lk_egg[menu.lk_egg['Item'] == item]['Type'].values[0]

Then the package is used:
from lunch import eggs
print(eggs.pickegg(2))

The table is not necessarily static e.g. there may be another module e.g. changemenu where you have add_egg(type) e.g. add_egg("scrambled").
Is the reference to menu.lk_egg within the other modules pythonic - or should I be doing it a different way?

Everything seems fine up until you said the menu isn't static. What does that mean? Does it mean that, within a runtime session, you can modify the menu but you're happy for it to default back to the example you've given on each run or are you looking for persistence?

Even without the issue of persistence against runs, every time you do from lunch import menu you will get the base menu because it's not a global object and it resets to the literal definition each time. And honestly, you really don't want to go down the path of making it global because it'll just be a mess

Thanks for the speedy response. If scrambled is added the table is saved to a central location. The menu module loads from this file. I simplified in the example.

It didn't need to be simplified in the example, you should have actually expanded on it. What you're basically saying now is that you do have some level of persistence, so the only real answer to this question is that it's subjective and I personally don't see any issues with your setup

Depending on how often the table changes, it might be better to use a database.
